# how to split a text file in c?

Tags: c, text, file-io

I am doing a Socket programming there i need to read a text file then i need to split that text file using tab space after that i need to assign each column to a defined array.

but in my code all fields are correct except the price column my price array always return the 0

How to fix that?

array declaration code

```
int id[10];
char name[10][50];
int qrty[10];
double price[10];
```

the following code is to split the text file and assign the values to the created array

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){ 
    sscanf(line,"%d\t%[^\t]\t%d\t%f",&pno,&pname,&qty,&uprice);
    Writen(sockfd,line,strlen(line));
    id[x]=pno;
    strncpy(name[x], pname, 50);
    qrty[x]=qty;
    price[x]=uprice;
    x++;
}
```

my text file is as follows

```
001 Coffee maker    10  3000.00

002 Pressure cooker 4   7000.00

003 Blender 10  2500.00

004 Pillow  10  300.00

005 Camera  5   25000.00

006 Washer  5   25000.00

007 Headphone   3   5000.00

008 Mattresses  5   6000.00

009 Heater  3   1000.00

010 Cookware    2   10000.00
```

Comment: there's a `%` missing before the bracket (`[`) in your format string

Comment: Are you sure the call to `sscanf` is working? You don't check it's return value.

Comment: What is `pno`, `pname`, `qty`, `uprice`? please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: though i put the % it is not working and sscanf is working

Comment: pno -> product number, pname-> product name, qty-> quantity, uprice-> Unit price and for an example pno= 001, pname= Coffee maker, qty= 10,price=3000.00

Comment: Isn't there a `%s` missing somewhere in the format string?

Comment: @MichaelWalz no, but a `%` ... the `[^\t]` should be the conversion captured in `pname`.

Comment: What is `char li[MAXCHAR];` supposed to do?

Comment: actually it is working this to perform the printing

Comment: Btw, `%[^\t]` is exactly like `%s` a guaranteed buffer overflow on "nasty" input data -- **always** use field widths with conversions to strings. Depending on the maximum size of your `line`, this might not be a problem .. just do it anyways :) Any reason for not using just `"%d %49s %d %f"`? Would be more flexible in allowing any whitespace as separator.

Comment: @FelixPalmen actually `"%d %49s %d %f"` wouldn't work because the the string in the second column may contain spaces (like in the first two lines of the OP's sample) and `%s` stops at the first space encountered.

Comment: @MichaelWalz alright, answers my question :) I didn't scroll up far enough....

Answer (score 2):

This works for me if, and only if the fields in the `a.txt` file are separated by TABs (not spaces):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char line[1000];
  FILE *fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");

  int pno, qty; 
  double uprice;
  char pname[100];

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    sscanf(line, "%d\t%[^\t]\t%d\t%lf", &pno, &pname, &qty, &uprice);
    printf("%d %s %d %lf\n", pno, pname, qty, uprice);
  }
}
```

You may even drop the `line` buffer by using `fscanf`:

```
 do
 {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %lf", &pno, &pname, &qty, &uprice) == 4)
      printf("%d %s %d %lf\n", pno, pname, qty, uprice);
 } while (!feof(fp));
```

Disclaimer: No error checking whatsoever is done here for brevity.

Comment: it worked than you so much @Michael Walz

Comment: `%lf` is only needed in `scanf`. In `printf` it can be just `%f`.

Comment: @ArturPasymowski that's correct, but `%lf` is nicer here for symmetrie.